# Decision between time or high-rank try

Tags: publications, paper-submission

Suppose you have a well-written paper that, in your supervisor's opinion,deserves a bit more of a Tier 2 journal, but it is difficult to get published in a Tier 1 journal. Would you suggest, in general, trying the higher rank journal first, getting a rejection (likely), but also possible improvements and eventually try a second-tier, or would you aim to the second straightforward to save time?

Comment: Work on it more till it becomes suitable for the better journal. You'll likely regret short selling good work in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circumstances can differ, but generally, unless you're in a sort of time trouble to get it published, it's never wrong to try a higher-impact journal first. In the worst case, you paper will be rejected by editor (and not sent for peer-review), which means that you won't lose too much time and will be able to submit it elsewhere.

Of course, it does not mean that you should send every paper of yours to Nature. In case of doubt, ask your supervisor if it has chances to be published in your journal of choice.

Answer (score 5):

I think you (or the hypothetical person here) are gaming the system to your own disadvantage. I'm reading the first sentence as "...more *than* a Tier 2 journal...".

You don't know you will be rejected. The suggestions of the reviewers might, when incorporated, result in acceptance.

And there is no guarantee about the time to publication for any journal. It is highly unpredictable for most journals, depending on the work load of reviewers, etc.

Moreover the break between "tiers" is pretty fuzzy.

Send it to the "most appropriate" journal for the work itself.